# How to find a copy of mesechta Derech Eretz online

Tags: jewish-books, masechet-derech-eretz

How to find

מסכת דרך ארץ רבה‏ and מסכת דרך ארץ זוטא‏

online in text and/or scan of a digital print?

(Wiki: [https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/מסכת_דרך_ארץ](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5))

I found this but can not copy the text.
http://maagarim.hebrew-academy.org.il/Pages/PMain.aspx?mishibbur=620000

Comment: I do not know what is the correct tag/s

Comment: What's wrong with the links at the bottom of that wikipedia page?

Comment: @DoubleAA zuta is good, but rabba I can not copy the text and the Hebrewbooks one is an old print (not digital clear)  , I guess it should be in the back of a gemoro but I do not know which one to check

Comment: Check the back of Horyot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily copiable text versions are available on Sefaria:

[Derekh Eretz Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Derekh_Eretz_Rabbah.1?lang=bi)

[Derekh Eretz Zuta](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Derekh_Eretz_Zuta.1?lang=bi)

Answer (score 3):

It is printed in the end of hoirios near the rest of the small mesehtois (h/t DoubleAA)

מסכת דרך ארץ רבה . Raba.
. 
On [Hebrewbooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37970&pgnum=681) (clear)

[text](http://maagarim.hebrew-academy.org.il/Pages/PMain.aspx?mishibbur=620000) not easily copiable

מסכת דרך ארץ זוטא. Zuta.
.
On [Hebrewbooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37970&pgnum=690) (clear)

[text](http://maagarim.hebrew-academy.org.il/Pages/PMain.aspx?misyzira=621000) not easily copiable
.
[text](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/zuta/shaar-2.htm)

Comment: very good links, particularly the last.

Answer (score 1):

The book appears to be on Hebrew Books
[מסכת דרך ארץ רבא וזוטא](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/36479) and is downloadable from there.